# Why doesn't work the useSwiper hook with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

I want to use the useSwiper hook to make clickable the carousel, but the useSwiper isn't recognized, when I log out to the console, then the value is undefined.
Here is the code:

```
<script setup>
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide, useSwiper} from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/css';

import {useRoomStore} from "../stores/RoomStore.js";


const swiper = useSwiper()
console.log(swiper)


const roomStore = useRoomStore()
</script>
```